# How can I add custom button in django admin to run django management command

Tags: python, django, django-management-command

I have to add an Update button in one of the model at my django-admin page and match_action is an update button on django-admin  and match_status is my management command, here is my code , actually I want , when I click update button I want to run a service named as goalserveService using management command

admin.py`

```
@admin.register(Match)
class MatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'start_time', "home_club", 'away_club', 'created_on', 'status', 'lookup_id', 'timer', 'match_actions']
    search_fields = ['id', 'home_club__name', 'away_club__name']
    list_filter = ['status', 'season', 'start_time']
    inlines = [ MatchLookupInline, MatchEventInline, ]

    def lookup_id(self, obj):
        if obj.matchlookup_set.all().exists():
            return obj.matchlookup_set.get().source_match_id
        else:
            return None
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
        url(
            r'^(?P<match_id>.+)/update/$',
            self.admin_site.admin_view(self.match_update),
            name='match-update',
        ),

        ]
        return custom_urls + urls

    def match_actions(self, obj):
        print (obj.id)
        return format_html(
            '<a class="button" href="{}">Update</a>',
            reverse('admin:match-update', args=(obj.id,)),

        )

    def match_update(self, request, match_id, *args):
        from django.core.management import call_command
        call_command("match_status", match_id)
```

core/management/commands/match_status.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from core.models import UserTeam
from ourapp.models import Match


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Update  Match Status'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('match_id', nargs='+', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # NOT_STARTED = 0
        # HF = 1
        # FT = 2
        # IN_PLAY = 3
        # FINISH = 4
        match = Match.objects.filter(id=options.get('match_id'))
        self.stdout.write(self.style.NOTICE("Match competition Name %s Match Found" % match.competition.name))
        current_time = timezone.now()


        try:
            import time

            self.stdout.write(self.style.NOTICE("Match competition Name %s Match Found" % match.competition.name if match.competition else "N/A"))

            match = Match.objects.filter(id=options.get('match_id'))
            time.sleep(5)
            from ourapp.services import goalserveService
            try:                        
                 goalserveService.run_match_events(match.pk, 2, update_df=False, update_round=False)
                 time.sleep(5)
            except:
                pass

            from django.core.management import call_command
            call_command("update_dfc_rank", 1)
        except Match.DoesNotExist:
            raise CommandError('League "%s" does not exist' % match)
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Successfully closed league "%s"' % match))
```

but it shows an error

[my admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNbz4.png)

[when I click update button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMktJ.png)

Comment: why not create util  function and do import it in the command and in the admin?

Comment: Share the whole traceback that you get in your console where you are running your Django development server

Answer (score -2):

Anytime you see `.objects.filter` in your code, you are returning a `QuerySet`. `QuerySet`s can be interpreted as a "list". For starters, replace `.filter` with `.get` to resolve the current error (but I cannot guarantee you won't run into a new error afterwards).